# How to serialize with and without root element with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I am using Jackson 1.9.x to serialize/deserialize object to/from JSON.

The requirement is that some objects must be serialized with root element and some must not. I know that I can switch this feature on/off with the code:

```
mapper.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

However I cannot set this globally since it needs to be changed at runtime.

I tried to use custom serializer but then when my custom 'serialize' method gets called I cannot disable root elements because the root element is already generated.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why not use two separate ObjecMapper instances?